# Movie With Half Sized Creature From Black Lagoon Surrounded By Suited Men With Rods

Tags: story-identification, movie

Apologies for lack of details in advance.
I'm am trying to place a movie that I saw a photo of in a Sci-Fi documentary book somewhere between 1979 to 1981.
There is a dwarf sized humanoid creature that looks similar to the Creature from the Black Lagoon. It is surrounded by men in I think radiation suits all armed with long rods, that I think glow at the pointy end. My impression was that it was a 50s or 60s movie but so far all my searches have failed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is from the 1929 version of Mysterious Island starring Lionel Barrymore.

[image: Mysterious Island still]

I've never actually seen it but grew up in the pre-VHS days reading about sci fi films. If I recall correctly what I read over 30 years ago, this is actually a publicity still which did not appear in the film.

Comment: That is definately the scene I was thinking off albeit I thought the creature was a little taller, the rods a bit more horizontal and the suits a little whiter. Thanks muchly.

Comment: Glad that the hours I spent reading these books have finally paid off!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's ["20 Million Miles to Earth"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050084/). The monster, the Ymir, was brought back from Venus. It starts out very small, but it keeps growing and growing.

[image: ymir]

Comment: I'm paging through it on the Internet Archive ( https://archive.org/details/20MillionMilesToEarth1957 ), but have not seen the scene yet.

Comment: I think I've seen that one. It's an old Ray Harryhausen if I'm not mistaken. I don't think that's it but I might check it out to be sure. Thanks for the help.